# "¿En qué periodo usted suele ver televisión?" is the usted necessary?

Tags: persona-gramatical

I am creating a survey to share among TV viewers from Uruguay, but I am not sure about my questions' structure.

*¿En qué periodo suele ver televisión? /
¿En qué periodo usted suele ver televisión?*

*¿Qué tipos de programas de televisión prefiere? /
¿Qué tipos de programas de televisión prefiere usted? / 
¿Qué tipos de programas de televisión usted prefiere?*

Is the "usted" necessary? And if it is, what is the correct position in the question?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary, as subject pronouns are typically omitted except when they are required to prevent ambiguity, or to emphasize the subject. In this case, if it's clear that you are talking about "usted", you don't need to repeat yourself. You could use "usted" in the first question, and then from time to time in some of the other questions, and omit it everywhere else.

As for word order, the verb almost always appears before the subject in questions with an interrogative particle (unless the interrogative particle comes after the verb: "¿Usted viene cuándo?", "¿Viene usted cuándo?", but this is unusual), so it would be "suele usted" and "prefiere usted". For questions without an interrogative particle, you could use either order.